# Red5 live streaming

Tags: streaming, stream, live, red5

I'm new with Red5. I would like to know how can I take a stream from a port (something like this rr.tt.yy.uu:1234) and publish it using Red5. I was looking the oflaDemo and the Simple Broadcaster included in Red5, but this only takes the camera and I need to take the stream. Can you help me please?, may be with an example or a guideline.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If its a flash stream you can use the RTMPClient, which is part of red5. If this is an RTSP stream or output from something like an Axis camera then you will need to consume it with something like Xuggler and probably transcode it before trying to access it with red5.

Comment: You may also restream from RTSP using this https://github.com/Red5/red5-rtsp-restreamer

Answer (score 0):

You cant publish a stream with Red5 with that kind of information i.e IP address and port number.

Answer (score 0):

Useful link for trancoding with red5: [Xuggler & ffmpeg](http://wiki.xuggle.com/Live_Encoding_Tutorial)
Please notice option -re (output in 'near real time' mode) must be in front of the input file, not after.

Answer (score -1):

well, basically it's netStream.Publish("someName")

Comment: This person is not asking how to publish a stream via action script, they want to know how to take a non-webcam stream and republish it via Red5.